# Navigation/Padding/Parent Divs

Tags: css, inheritance, navigation, parent, html

I am trying to design a navigation menu that is centered that sits within a div that spans 100% width of the screen.  I have my navigation divs within a parent div called navigation, and that parent div is within a navigation container.  I felt this was necessary to have a centered navigation within this 100% width parent div.

The problem is that I am not having luck getting the parent div to expand with the appropriate padding I give to the navItem divs.  Sorry if this is kind of confusing, thanks for any advice offered.

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>
            MC Machine Test
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="top">
    </div>
    <div class="navContainer">
        <div class="navigation">
            <div class="navItem">Home</div>
            <div class="navItem">Products</div>
            <div class="navItem">Facility</div>
            <div class="navItem">Photo Gallery</div>
            <div class="navItem">Request a Quote</div>
            <div class="navItem">Contact Us</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mainSection">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Here is the CSS.**

```
.navContainer
{
    width:100%;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    color:#333333;
    border-bottom:solid 1px #333333;
}

.navigation
{
    border:0px 1px 1px 0px solid #333333;
    width:680px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
.navItem
{
    padding:20px;
    border-right:1px solid #cccccc;
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: <body>
 <div class="top">
 </div>
 <div class="navContainer">
  <div class="navigation">
   <div class="navItem">Home</div>
   <div class="navItem">Products</div>
   <div class="navItem">Facility</div>
   <div class="navItem">Photo Gallery</div>
   <div class="navItem">Request a Quote</div>
   <div class="navItem">Contact Us</div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="mainSection">
 </div>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be mistaken here but I think you can't add top/bottom padding to inline elements. If I understood what you want to do correctly, you could define the display as block and use floats to make them stand next to each other as opposed to below each other.

```
.navItem
{
    padding:20px;
    border-right:1px solid #cccccc;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Ah, ok it seemed like that might be the problem since the parent divs didn't have a set height preventing it.  I will be enclosing these divs within a link tag as well, does that change anything?  Thanks for the quick answer btw

Comment: As Diodeus pointed out, lists make more sense than divs for menus so check that link out. I believe you meant you'll be adding link tags inside the divs right? What I usually do in those situations is declare the links with display: block and set them to the same dimensions as the parent element so that its entire area is clickable.

Comment: Revolt, actually I meant that I wanted the each div to be its own link.  That way the user has doesn't have to click on the exact link text, just seems more usable, imo.  I guess by doing it this way I am creating an extra step?

Comment: Well, in order to have a link you need a <a> element. What I said is to put that <a> element inside each .navItem div and set the display of the <a> element to block and set its size to the size of the navItem. This way the entire area of the .navItem will be clickable. You might have to play around with the line-height property if you want the text centered on the <a> element. For example, set height:30px and line-height:30px on the <a> elements.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use DIVs to build menus. Use styled unordered lists.

See: [I love lists](http://preview.moveable.com/jm/ilovelists/).

Comment: I used to used ul's to build menus but someone told me that it is better to just use div's, then you don't have to get rid of bullets and both a div and a list is a block level element anyways

Comment: A list represents a collection semantically, allowing bots and screen readers to recognize it as a list. This is important stuff. It's easy to get rid of the bullets and you have to add CSS anyway, so it's no big deal.